# rajya sabha website scraper using R and PhantomJS

Tags: r, web-scraping, phantomjs

i want to scrape the pdf hyperlinks on the website:
http://164.100.47.5/newsite/floor_official_debate/floor_official_debate.aspx

```
var args = require('system').args;

var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webpage.create();

var fs   = require('fs');
var url  = 'http://164.100.47.5/newsite/floor_official_debate/floor_official_debate.aspx';
var path = 'd.html'

page.open(url, function (status) {
  var content = page.content;
  fs.write(path,content,'w')
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Not sure why this does not create d.html file in the working directory?
Then in a separately execute the below

```
system("F:/india political/rajya sabha floor debate/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe get_RSdoc.js")

withJS <- read_html('d.html') %>%
  html_nodes("//a") %>%
  html_text
```

the text/link i want to extract is under href:http://164.100.47.5/Official_Debate_Nhindi/Floor/1/F14.08.1952.pdf
This is what i want to download across all sessions 1:250.